# What would you advise between iAd and adSense

Tags: iphone, ios, ads

I'm thinking about including an add in my app. What advertising programme would you recommend me between iAd and adSense ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic has been covered quite a few times before. It depends on what you want in the end. With iAd, the eCPM is high but the fill rate is low especially out of the US. On the flip side, with Admob, the eCPM is low(er) but the fill rate is higher than iAd.

What you could do is get the best of both worlds and use something like [AdWhirl](https://www.adwhirl.com/) to show both types of Ads by rotating through the different ad networks

Answer (score 1):

There's not much reason to go with only one. Get two or more ad networks to leverage your inventory.

Fill rates can fall for many a reason: end of an ad campaign, server error, etc.. If you have a back up, it'll fill up the fill rate. Additionally, you'll be able to compare which ad networks optimize and target ads for your demographic(s) better!